# Foreign key to composite key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a problem i need to reference a single foreign key to a composite key in another table.

My database structure is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE available_trip (
trip_code integer not null,
date datetime not null,
primary key(trip_code, date),
FOREIGN KEY (trip_code) REFERENCES trip (trip_code)
);

CREATE TABLE booking (
    available_trip_code integer not null,
    customer_code integer not null,
    date datetime not null,
    deposit float not null,
    total_price float not null,
    has_paid float not null,
    description_en nvarchar(12) null,
    finance_type_code nvarchar(12) not null,
    primary key(available_trip_code, customer_code, date),
    FOREIGN KEY (available_trip_code) REFERENCES available_trip (trip_code, date),


FOREIGN KEY (customer_code) REFERENCES customer (customer_code),
            FOREIGN KEY (finance_type_code) REFERENCES finance_type (finance_type_code)
        );
```

my question is: how do I let `booking.available_trip_code` reference to `available_trip.trip_code` and `available_trip.date` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you reference a composite primary key, your foreign key also needs to contain all those columns - so you need something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (available_trip_code, date) 
            REFERENCES available_trip (trip_code, date)
```

If you don't already have all those columns present in your table, then you'll need to add them.

Comment: I've been using SQL Server for 7 years ... never knew this was a thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
alter table booking add constraint FK_Booking_TripAndDate
    foreign key (available_trip_code,date)
    references available_trip(trip_code, date)
```