# If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table Favorites whose definition is like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Favorites] (
    [username] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [imdbId]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([username] ASC, [imdbId] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([username]) REFERENCES [dbo].[proj_users] ([username])
);
```

Now I have one more table TopMovies

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].TopMovies (
    [imdbId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    [count] INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([imdbId], [count]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TopMovies_Favorites] FOREIGN KEY ([imdbId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Favorites] ([imdbId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

When I try to create this table, I get the following error:

"The referenced table '[dbo].[Favorites]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted."

Comment: you should try to add the extra column of `id` and put primary key and  in `Favorites` table

Comment: I am not sure how id would help me, can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do create the FK of TopMovies because, the PK of Favorites has 2 columns and you are just referencing only 1. I mean on one side you have :

- Favorites with composite PK
- TopMovies try to use FK on 1 column of composite PK

You shoud have something like this in TopMovies :

```
FOREIGN KEY([username], [imdbId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Favorites]([username], [imdbId])
```

Here you have the exact same issue : [StackOverflow foreign key composite primary key sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575138/3503205)

You have to choose between, change composite PK of Favorite to simple PK or to add the missing column in FK table.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is not properly normalized. `imdb` should be a separate entity (table), referenced by both Favorites and TopMovies.

On a side note, the PK on TopMovies looks suspicius as well.

Comment: This is true, but even after he adds the `imdb` table, he will still have the problem of leaving a column out of the foreign key.

Comment: No, he won't, because the FK will be from TopMovies(imdbId) to imdb(imdb) -- a single column, btw.

Comment: @dean: That depends. I read his spec as requiring that a TopMovie be already a Favorite (i.e., a super-favorite), and in that case the FK is still to the `Favorites` table, and it is still two columns. Your reading is that TopMovie and Favorite are distinct special movies, and each one separately references the new `IMDB` entity.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Right. Hopefully, OP knows which one is correct :)