# Can't set a foreign key between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, unique, primary-key, entity-relationship

I have 2 tables:

```
Clients
-------
(PK)id
family
name
...
(PK)idprovincia
(PK)idsesion


Brothers
--------
(PK)id
(PK)idclient
name
```

I want to set a foreign key between Brothers and Clients. I mean, a client can have several brothers but SQL Server doesn't let me to do that.

However I could set idprovincia and idsesion to PROVINCIAS and SESIONES (other tables that I didn't specified because there is no problem with them)

Also I tried to set idclient as UNIQUE but, one more time, SQL Server Management Studio doesn't let me to make the foreign key.

How can I manage that?

Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to do a compound key that contains a foreign key as well. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575046/foreign-key-to-composite-key.

Comment: "If you reference a composite primary key, your foreign key also needs to contain all those columns - so you need something like", means that you can't have idsession or idprovincia also as Primary Keys because they are not foreign keys in the Brothers table.

Comment: maybe you should post the error message

Comment: Do you have to have all of those columns set as primary keys? You already have an ID column.

Comment: (PK)idclient in Table Brothers should be FK, and it should not be unique. PK id in clients Table is OK: other fields in that Table are immaterial to this question: just apply a unique constraint but do not make them PK. Best regards,

Comment: Should idprovincia, idsesion and idclient be set as Unique then?

Comment: can't brothers be clients? what if you have two clients who are brothers and have another non-client brother?

Comment: "Should idprovincia, idsesion and idclient be set as Unique then" - it depends on your business logic: if two clients may have the same idprovincia, then obviously not. You should made the decision based on your data model. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question:

### Clients

```
(PK)id - identity field, auto-incremented
family
name
...
idprovincia (could have unique constraints or not - doesn't matter in this case)
idsesion (could have unique constraints or not - doesn't matter in this case)
```

### Brothers

```
(PK)id - identity field, auto-incremented
(FK)idclient (not unique as it participates in One-to-Many relationship)
name
```

Also make sure that the PK/FK use the same data type.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Hi, I set idprovincia as pk because it can be unique for the reason you said in a comment above and set idsession as unique. However I need to set idclient as pk because it could be repeated. But I get the same result... I don't know what to do then.

Comment: Actually, I said just a vice versa: do NOT set every unique field as PK. In this very simple One-to-Many type of relationship you should have only one PK per each Table. DO NOT set idclient neither PK nor unique: it's an FK (their might be duplicate values in this column, so do NOT apply unique constraints to this field). Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: But Alex, maybe I'm wrong but if I don't set idcliente as PK or UNIQUE I can't create a foreign key on it.  Sorry for my ignorance man

Comment: No, you create a One-to-Many relationship between two Tables, where Clients is on "One" side and it has PK id and Brothers (on "Many" side) with idclient field used as FK. It ensures the referential integrity which means that Brothers Table may have many rows with the same Client id which guaranteed to exist in a first table. Regards,

Comment: Finally I did, I was wrong cos I thought I need that both relationed members had to be primarys or primary and unique but was easy than expected when I read your comments.

Comment: You are very welcome! :) I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted. Best of luck with your project. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint is to create zero to many cardinality that ensures that the second table that has the primary key of first table in it has data for each primary key.
For Ex: A customer id in an e-commerce DB act as primary key in customer table and it is referred as foreign key in order table. A customer can have 0 to n number of orders in order table. Here the foreign key assures that the customer is linked to each order he has made.

As to your table:-

Clients:

(PK) client_Id - autogen
  Family name
  ..
Brothers:

(PK) brother_Id - autogen
 (FK) client_Id 
  Family name